# In Ruby, what is the return value in a loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

Using the following code:

```
  def get_action
    action = nil
    until Guide::Config.actions.include?(action)
      puts "Actions: " + Guide::Config.actions.join(", ")
      print "> "
      user_response = gets.chomp
      action = user_response.downcase.strip
    end
    return action
  end
```

The following code takes the user response, and eventually returns its actions to another method.

I know that a loop repeats itself until its ultimately broken, but was curious about the return value, so I could better structure the loop for next time. In the `until` loop, I am curious to know whether what value does the `until` loop return, if there is a return value at all?

Comment: Are you asking what `x` will be if you `x = until .... end`?

Comment: Asking what the return value is in a loop `until some condition .... end` (does not even have to be this example, but in general), similar to how the return value of a method is the last line or when the `return` keyword is used

Comment: `return` breaks the loop. Assignment `x = ... etc` as mits says, will assign `nil` to `x`.

Comment: @sagarpandya82, assign `x` to loop will assign `x` to what internal `break` returns. by default it is `nil` but you can explicitly return `break "something"` so the result of the loop will be "something"

Comment: @fl00r I keep getting ``<main>': unexpected return (LocalJumpError)` when I attempt to do this?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 check it out `x = loop do break "something"; end`

Comment: @fl00r gotcha, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the return of a loop (`loop`, `while`, `until`, etc) can be anything you send to `break`

```
def get_action
  loop do
    action = gets.chomp
    break action if Guide::Config.actions.include?(action)
  end
end
```

or

```
def get_action
  while action = gets.chomp
    break action if Guide::Config.actions.include?(action)
  end
end
```

or you can use `begin .. while`

```
def get_action
  begin
    action = gets.chomp
  end while Guide::Config.actions.include?(action)
  action
end
```

or even shorter

```
def get_action
  action = gets.chomp while Guide::Config.actions.include?(action)
  action
end
```

PS: loops themselves return nil as a result (implicit `break` which is `break nil`) unless you use explicit `break "something"`. If you want to assign result of the loop you should use `break` for this: `x = loop do break 1; end`

Comment: So loops don't return anything, unless you put a `break` statement and that `break` statement works similarly to `return`  in methods?

Comment: break will return something from the loop itself so you can assign it to a variable and continue execution of a method. `return` will exit a method immediately.

Comment: @programmer321: Yes, `break` will a) immediately terminate the loop and b) make the loop evaluate to the value passed to `break` in exactly the same way that `return` will immediately terminate a method (or lambda) and make the method call evaluate to the value passed to `return`, and `next` will immediately terminate a block and make the block evaluate to the value being passed to `next`. The main difference is what happens if the respective keyword is *not* used: blocks, methods, and lambdas (as well module and class definitions) evaluate to the value of the last expression that is evaluated

Comment: … whereas `while` and `until` loops evaluate to `nil`. A `for`/`in` iterator, OTOH, is kind of syntactic sugar for `each` and simply evaluates to the return value of `each` (which per the standard protocol is `self`, but that is not enforced in any way).

Comment: Excellent analysis @JörgWMittag!

Answer (score 0):

`loop` can also return a value without using a `break`

```
def loop_return
  @a = [1, 2, 3 ].to_enum
  loop do
    @a.next
  end
end

print loop_return  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```